# Find the orthogonal projection of a vector v onto U

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, transpose

I am trying to solve this question:

Let $u$ be a unit vector in $R^n$ and let $U$ be the subspace spanned by $u$. Show that the orthogonal projection of a vector $v$ onto $U$ is given by

$\operatorname{proj}_{U}v = (uu^T)v$,

and thus that the matrix of this projection is $uu^T$. What is the rank of $uu^T$?

Where $u^T$ is the transpose of $u$. Any help is appreciate! I have no idea how to begin this other than knowing

$\operatorname{proj}_{U}v = \frac{(v, u)u}{(u, u)}$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The projection formula you have is the solution. $\left(u,u\right)=1$,
since $u$ is a unit vector. So 
\begin{align*}
\text{Proj}_{U}v & =\left(v,u\right)u=\left(u^{T}v\right)u=\left(uu^{T}\right)v.
\end{align*}

Comment: So the projection of $v$ is collinear to itself?

Comment: Thanks for your help! What did you do to get from (v, u)u to (uT, v)u?

Comment: Oh, $(v,u)=u^{T}v$, and so $(v,u)u=(u^{T}v)u$. Perhaps an example helps. Take $u=\left(1,0,0\right)$ as a column vector; then
\begin{align*}
\text{Proj}_{U} & =u^{T}u=\begin{bmatrix}1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh, so this is just a known property of the dot product. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The general formula in any inner product space, whether $u$ be  a unit vector or not is

$$\operatorname{Proj}_U(v)=\frac{\langle\, v,u\,\rangle}{\langle\, u,u\,\rangle}u=\frac{\langle\, v,u\,\rangle}{\lVert u\rVert^2}u$$
Here $\lVert u\rVert=1$, hence the formula comes down to $$\operatorname{Proj}_U(v)=\langle\, v,u\,\rangle u.$$
Now in $\mathbf R^n$ equipped with the Euclidean inner product, $\,\langle\, v,u\,\rangle={}^{\mathrm t\mkern-1mu}v\mkern2mu u$, when $u$ and $v$ are represented by column vectors.

Comment: I'm not understanding the transition from the inner product to the multiplication with the transpose vector. Can you explain that part more?

Comment: Just multiply a $1\times n$ matrix by a $n\times 1$ matrix, an,d compare with the dot product. The product of two matrices is made up of the dot products of the rows of the first matrix with the columns of the second matrix.